# Applescript to delete a file, that name does not contain "_s"

Tags: applescript, automator

I am a newbie totally in applescript, so saying that..
What I want to do is delete specific files inside a folder. For example:

I have this files:

- C9361WL_1.jpg
- C9361WL_1.jpg
- C9361WL_2.jpg
- C9361WL_3.jpg
- C9361WL_4.jpg
- C9361WL_1_s.jpg
- C9361WL_2_s.jpg
- C9361WL_3_s.jpg
- C9361WL_4_s.jpg

I want to delete the files that doesn't contain "_s" inside the name file.

Thank you in advance for any help.

The code I wrote in Automator is:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    repeat with this_file in input

        if this_file does not contain "_s" then
            delete this_file
        end if
    end repeat
    return input
end run
```

Still not luck with this script, I already do some changes

```
on run {input, parameters}
    repeat with this_file in input
        set thePath to POSIX file of this_file as alias
        set delFiles to (every file of thePath whose name does not contain "_s")
        tell application "Finder"
            move files of delFiles to "/Users/dyohanan/Desktop/"
        end tell
    end repeat
    return input
end run
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost, but you need to tell the `Finder` to perform the delete operation and you want to check the **name** of the file.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    repeat with this_file in input
        tell application "Finder"
            if name of this_file does not contain "_s" then
                delete this_file
            end if
        end tell
    end repeat
    return input
end run
```

Comment: Hi vadian, thank you for your help. I did what you told me and now I received an error message telling me:
SYNTAX ERROR: "CAN'T MAKE NAME OF ITEM 1 INTO TYPE REFERENCE"

Comment: The script assumes that `input` is a list of alias specifiers.

Comment: you was right, the error came when I tested with just one item instead of a list.
But now i do not receive an error but the script doesn't delete the files.